# Python - Countdown timer that exits program after given time

Tags: python, timer, countdown, puzzle

I'm pretty new in Python, and I'm working with my colleagues from college on simple puzzle project. We want to update the program and add timer & reset button to it.

The idea of timer is to countdown for X minutes and then show some message with quit/exit button or just quit the main app.
Reset button can be placed somewhere in the app window and reset the game.

Program can be found here: http://pastebin.com/79zRqhnH

Thanks for any help.

A.

Comment: Please post the relevant code sections within the main body.

As far as exiting the program within a time frame, if you have a repetitive loop that cycles frequently enough for your needs, you can simply exit once a condition (such as `time.time()` being less than a value) is broken. If you need to exit a function that may not have a loop, you will have to look at the `threading` module in the built-in library.

Answer (score 0):

just a few suggestions first, though keep in mind i'm also not a code expert.

i would suggest that you import the turtle, and call `turtle.FUNCTIONNAME` when in need for the certain function, even just for the sake of readability later on (although i'm pretty sure that its also better in terms of memory and code run time to not import all of the functions at once, which is what happens when you call `FROM libraryname import *`).

also you could initialize your variables in your `MAIN` function rather than globally on the file, for readability and organization, and also if you'd ever want to import the functions in this file, then global variables not initialized in `MAIN` will get in the way.

also try to keep your code organized in functions, in your current example the turtle functions you've called are scattered throughout with no reason, where you could've wrapped all of them inside a new function and call that function once instead.

lastly make sure to delete turtle.exitonclick() call you have at the end of your program.

```
import tkMessageBox
import turtle
def main () :
    turtle.onscreenclick(getPos)
    SetTimer() #call for the function to setup the timer, you can call this function when certain conditions are met rather than at startup.
    mainloop()

def SetTimer():
    canvas = turtle.getcanvas() #get current turtle canvas to set the after call on.
    canvas.after(2000, CalledAfter2000ms, canvas) #first parameter specifies time in miliseconds to wait before the call to CalledAfter2000ms function which is in the second paramater, the third paramater here is the paramater im passing to the CalledAfter2000ms function.

def CalledAfter2000ms(canvas): #function passed to canvas.after(...)
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno("EXIT","Do you really want to exit?"): #if yes is pressed, True is returned, if no is pressed then False is returned.
        turtle.bye() #exits the application
```